# Bootstrap3 Navs not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like my site to have a menu with tabs like the one shown
in Twitter Bootstrap website.

I have downloaded jquery 1.11.2 in the `js/` folder and placed the following
in the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 

<!--- Google  fonts-->    

<!-- javascript libraries -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--- personal styles should always be below bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">
```

Next to get the Navs menu I copied and paste the code from the Bootstrap component page ( I just changed the text to display)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 site-menu">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

The navs however do not look the way I expected, the links are shown as a bulletted list.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get to display Navs Tabs ans Navs pills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't linked the CSS files properly, try with the **latest** version CDN links,

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

```html
<!--- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--- personal styles should always be below Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">-->

<!--- Google  fonts-->


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 site-menu">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The general outline of the html file should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS-->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700|Amatic+SC:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- My Theme style -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!--lots of html-->
  <!--lots of html-->
  <!--lots of html-->


  <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Core JS -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
    <!-- some JS Function -->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks. Two things are clear to me though.. where should I place the JQuery calls? (and why mine are not linked correctly? I would like to use my self-hosted rather than relying on a CDN)

Comment: It's a good practice to place Javascript libraries (jquery.min.js, bootstrap.min,js etc.) just before the closing body tag `</body>`. If you are making calls to any functions in those libraries, place it after you have linked them, again just before the closing `</body>` tag

Comment: OK, using the CDN and moving the libraries before </body> didn't fix my issue though...

Comment: could you make a JsFiddle and provide a link?

Comment: using the cdn version of bootstrap though, made the tabs appear correctly, maybe I just have to change the bootstrap.min.css in my css folder

Comment: I have added an example outline, have a look.

Comment: the issue was I had bootstrap 3.3.2. Upgrading to 3.3.4 fixed the issue for me! Thanks (can you add something like "make sure you have the latest version of bootstrap", or something similar to your answer, to reflect better what my issue was?)